# How to split a string on all non-alphanumeric, but also keep the delimiters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a string by all non-alphanumeric characters (apart from `#`) but without loosing the delimiters.

**For example:**

```
'this #string is 2b #split&like this'
```

**Should return:**

```
['this ','#string ','is ','2b ','#split','&like ','this']
```

**So far I have:**

```
text.split(/((?=[^\w#])|(?<=[^\w#]))/g);
```

which looks almost looks like it works fine in: http://regex101.com/r/eT1fQ9

but this give me this error in my browser:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /((?=[^\w#])|(?<=[^\w#]))/: Invalid group
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds.

Comment: @FelixKling ahh thanks!.. do you know of a way of doing this without lookbehinds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var text = 'this #string is 2b #split&like this #';
var arr = text.split(/((?=.)\W*(\w+\s*|$))/g).filter(Boolean);
//=> ["this ", "#string ", "is ", "2b ", "#split", "&like ", "this", "#"]
```

OR using `String#match`:

```
var arr = text.match(/((?=.)\W*(\w+\s*|$))/g)
//=> ["this ", "#string ", "is ", "2b ", "#split", "&like ", "this", "#"]
```

Comment: the only thin wrong with this is that it trims of the final delimiters. For example 'this #string is 2b #split&like this #' the last '#' is trimmed off

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `string.match` method, and pass a regexp with the global flag set. The return value will then be a list with all matches:

```
'this #string is 2b #split&like this'
    .match(/(?=.)[^a-z0-9#]*[a-z0-9#]+[^a-z0-9#]*/gi)
// ["this ","#string ","is ","2b ","#split&","like ","this"]
```

Basically, the RegExp is constructed as follows:

```
(?=.)                              To prevent empty strings
[ inverted class of delimiters ]*  To match optional leading delimiters
[ class of delimiters ]+           To match the other characters
[inverted class of delimiters]*    To match optional trailing delimiters
```

Comment: OP says `'this ','#string '` I think you are missing the space(or in other words, the delimiters).

Comment: @SabujHassan Edited pattern.

Comment: Thanks for this @RobW! I'm just trying to get '#split&','like ' to be '#split','&like '

Comment: @user988116 The description in your question did not match your desired outcome. Apparently, you're not just delimiting by alphanumerics, because a space is treated different from the &. Compare `"#string ", "is"` with `"#split", "&like"`. According to what rule did the `&` go with `like` instead of `#split`? For your current input, the other answer may work, but if you don't define the exact pattern rules, then sooner or later, you will find an edge-case where the input does not produce the desired output.

Comment: yes you're right, I guess I should be looking for: split before any non-alphanumeric character apart from space, in which case split after it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
arr = str.match(/([^\w#]+|^)([\w#]+)/g).map(function(s){ return s.trim() });
```