# Split a string into an array of words and punctuation marks

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a string:

```
this.sentence = 'I have a brother, sister, a dog, and a cat.'
```

I want to convert it into an array so that each word and each punctuation mark is a separate value. Using `.split(" ")` gives me an array of words, but does not put each comma and a dot as a separate value.

How can I do this so that I get such array

```
["I", "have", "a", "brother", ",", "sister", ",", "a", "dog", ",", "and", "a", "cat", "."]
```

I don't really want to use `.match` and regex as I need to include special Polish characters in my sentences

Comment: Not sure what Polish character has to do with anything, but [How to split a string on all non-alphanumeric, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23066272/215552) seems like what you want...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string on all non-alphanumeric, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066272/how-to-split-a-string-on-all-non-alphanumeric-but-also-keep-the-delimiters)

Comment: @JohnnyBravo There appears to be a comment under your answer which explains the reasoning for the downvote. Not sure why you're addressing me in the comments on the question....

Comment: My bad, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to split them with regex

```js
const args = this.sentence.trim().split(/\b|\b(?=\W)/)?.filter((e)=>e.trim() !=="");

console.log(args)
```

But, not sure if you don't want use regex.

Comment: Why do you have this as an alternative? `|\b(?=\W)`

Comment: Hi thank you for this solution, but it also splits polish characters so it's not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

```js
const string = 'I have a brother, sister, a dog, and a cat.';

// Split the string into an array of words
const result = string.split(' ');
   
// Iterate over the array
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  // Check if the word includes a comma      
  if (result[i].includes(',')) {
    // Remove the comma from the word
    result[i] = result[i].replace(',', '');
    // Insert the comma as a separate element in next position of the aray
    result.splice(i + 1, 0, ',');
    // Skip next iteration since we've added the comma and move onto next word
    i += 1;
  }
  // *Repeat same process as above but for periods
  if (result[i].includes('.')) {
    result[i] = result[i].replace('.', '');
    result.splice(i + 1, 0, '.'); 
    i += 1;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```